# Key code on firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, onkeypress

I have to disable some symbols from html input.
`e.which` is not working properly on Firefox. Firefox disables `backspace` and ect.
Here is [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvs6u/13/):

```
var code = window.event ? event.keyCode : e.which;
```

`event.keyCode` works on firefox, but does not work with `String.fromCharCode(code)`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery normalizes `e.which`, so you don't have to worry about this at all.
Also, it's a lot easier to just listen for the correct keycodes, there's no reason to convert the keycode to a character just to filter it out with `indexOf` ?

```
$('#foo').keydown(function(e) {
    var code = e.which;
    if (code == 8 || code == 13) return true; // backspace and enter
    if (code < 48 || code > 57 || code == 188 || code == 190) return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fvs6u/11/)

To keep most keys active, and just mainly disable characters, you could filter like this

```
$('#foo').keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && 
        key >= 48 && key <= 57 ||  // numbers   
        key >= 96 && key <= 105 || // Numeric keypad
        key == 190 || key == 188 || key == 109 || key == 110 || // comma, period and minus, . on keypad
        key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 ||  // Backspace and Tab and EnterEnd
        key == 35 || key == 36 || // Home and 
        key == 37 || key == 39 || // left and right arrows
        key == 46 || key == 45) // Del and Ins
        return true;

    return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fvs6u/16/)

Comment: Backspace STILL NOT WORKING on firefox - that is main problem

Comment: @Srw - You're blocking everything **BUT** numbers, comma and period, of course backspace doesn't work, if you'd like to allow that character you have to add it to a whitelist, I'll update the answer.

Comment: now i need arrow, del and ect. )) what is general solution to affect only symbols?

Comment: What you gonna do with russian keyboard layout, shift+? puts a dot on it. Shall i look after Shift key?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two errors in your script:

1. you called the event parameter `event` but referred to `e.which`.

<s>2. you have to call `evt.preventDefault()` for preventing the typed character to appear.</s>

The latter point is wrong when adding jQuery event handlers. 'Normal' DOM handlers require `preventDefault()`, see also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false#comment10263970_1357151).

[→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvs6u/12/)

```
$('#foo').keypress(function(evt) {
    var code = window.event ? event.keyCode : evt.which;
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(code);
    if ("0123456789.,".indexOf(chr) < 0) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: evt.preventDefault(); equals to return false

Comment: @Srw You're right, at least when using jQuery event handlers.